# Too much drop in 3 inch pvc line?

Tags: basement, drain, pvc

I'm redoing old rotten cast iron and I have a problem with a gas line in the way. Is a 9 inch drop too much in a 6 foot run of 3" pvc coming from the water closet to the main stack?

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that the 9 inch drop is any sort of problem. After all some parts of your drainage system will have a total vertical drop which is the maximal case of drop. The main reason of specifying drop per horizontal distance is to spec out the minimal amount of drop to allow drainage flow to work.

Comment: Thanks Michael, glad to know its no problem. Reading the forums has also led me to realize that I can also do an offset to get where I need to be.

Comment: This is not entirely correct. Issues can arise when pipes are installed with too much slope. I've posed an answer that explains further.

Answer (score 1):

When talking about drainage, anything 45° or more is concerned nominally vertical. Anything less than 45° is nominally horizontal.

The specified slopes for horizontal pipes should not be considered as a minimum. When there is too much slope (somewhere grater than the minimum but less than 45°) you can create an issue were the water will drain faster than the solids, leaving the solids behind. This results in build up of solids and eventually can cause backups in the system.

The other issue is that the fall of a trap arm should not exceed the inside diameter of the pipe. The trap arm is the portion of pipe between the fixture trap and the vent connection that serves that fixture. When this fall is exceeded, the effective of the vent is lost and drainage issues can occur.